# How to make manual batch in pytorch with MNIST dataset

Tags: pytorch, mnist, batchsize

I am new to pytorch.

I am trying to use a different approach when training MNIST dataset in pytorch.

Normally, we put all shuffled numbers for each batch.

What I want to do is (assuming by batch size is 20 and there are 1000 training examples).
Make a batch look this this (I wrote only labels for simplicity)

---

batch_1 = [0, 0, 1, 0, ... ] only 0 and 1 for this batch

batch_2 = [6, 6, 7, 7, ... ] only 6 and 7 for this batch

batch_3 = [2, 3, 2, 2, ... ] only 2 and 3 for this batch

batch_4 = [4, 5, 5, 4, ... ] only 4 and 5 for this batch

batch_5 = [6, 6, 7, 7, ... ] only 6 and 7 for this batch

batch_6 = [8, 9, 9, 9, ... ] only 8 and 9 for this batch

batch_7 = [2, 3, 2, 2, ... ] only 2 and 3 for this batch

batch_8 = [4, 5, 5, 4, ... ] only 4 and 5 for this batch

...

batch_50 = [4, 5, 5, 4, ... ] only 4 and 5 for this batch

---

How can I do this in pytorch??

Thank you

---

So far this is my implementation for training / testing.
I will expand/manipulate this code below to develop the above.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Subset
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torchvision import transforms
import numpy as np

mnist_trainset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, 
                                download=True, 
                                transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))

mnist_testset  = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', 
                                train=False, 
                                download=True, 
                                transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))

class_inds = [torch.where(mnist_trainset.targets == class_idx)[0]
              for class_idx in mnist_trainset.class_to_idx.values()]

train_dataloaders = [
                     DataLoader(dataset=Subset(mnist_trainset, inds),
                                batch_size=50,
                                shuffle=True,
                                drop_last=False
                     )
                     for inds in class_inds
]

test_dataloader  = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_testset, 
                                               batch_size=50, 
                                               shuffle=False)

class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear_1 = torch.nn.Linear(784, 256)
        self.linear_2 = torch.nn.Linear(256, 10)
        self.sigmoid  = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.linear_1(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        pred = self.linear_2(x)

        return pred

model = Model()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
epochs = 20

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

test_acc   = list()

for epoch in range(epochs):

    print(f"epoch {epoch} started")

    model.train()
    itr = 0 
    iterators = list(map(iter, train_dataloaders))   
    while iterators:
        itr = itr + 1 
        iterator = np.random.choice(iterators)
        try:
            image, label = next(iterator)   

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            pred = model(image)

            loss = criterion(pred, label)

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            
        except StopIteration:
            iterators.remove(iterator)

    model.eval()
    total = 0
    for itr, (image, label) in enumerate(test_dataloader):

        pred = model(image)

        loss = criterion(pred, label)

        # we now need softmax because we are testing.
        pred = torch.nn.functional.softmax(pred, dim=1)
        for i, p in enumerate(pred):
            if label[i] == torch.max(p.data, 0)[1]:
                total = total + 1

    accuracy = total / len(mnist_testset)

    # append accuracy here
    test_acc.append(accuracy)
```

Comment: You need to look into [custom datasets](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html)

Comment: Yes I have already looked into that webpage; however I still don't get what I need to do and that is why I posted a question on here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batches of points with the same label on Pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60725571/batches-of-points-with-the-same-label-on-pytorch)

Comment: @trialNerror Thank you very much. I think it will help me out. If possible, could you please give me an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Well I would follow the implementation from the answer I linked, but instead of randomly chosing one loader, you choose 2 out of 10. Then take one batch from the first loader, one batch from second loader, concatenate them along batch dimension and voilà ! you have a 2 labels batch. Try it out and if you have any implementation issue, don't hesitate to enhance your question with what you tried and what failed

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I will try that soon within this week and get back to you!